# Two peaks finding algorithm

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer

We are given an array of length N with exactly 2 peaks (a peak is an element which is no less than the left and right neighbors). Is there an algorithm to compute those peaks faster than *O(N)*, maybe similar with the single peak finding in *O(log N)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Any algorithm to locate those two peaks will take $\Omega(N)$ time, assuming that the only operation allowed is to compare two elements in the array, i.e., the comparison mode.

Otherwise, suppose algorithm $A$ do not need that much time. Let $arr[0], arr[1], \cdots, arr[N-1]$ be the given array. Then for some $N$ large enough, $A$ will have only checked at most $N-3$ elements before it has terminated. Suppose for all comparisons that have done by $A$, it will be found that $arr[i] < arr[j]$ where $i<j$.

Let $arr[a], arr[b], arr[c]$ be three elements that have not been checked yet, $a<b<c$. Whatever $A$ have done, the two peaks could be $\{arr[a], arr[N-1]\}$. They can be $\{arr[b], arr[N-1]\}$ as well. Since $A$ cannot distinguish these two cases, $A$ cannot possibly have determined the two peaks.

**Exercise.** (less than one minute) Modify the above argument so that it becomes valid in the case when a peak must have both left neighbor and right neighbor.